# Need Help With a Minecraft Command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Wanting to make an ender eye that will give the user levitation while holding it, I've tried a bunch of commands but they were all for 1.13. Anyone know a 1.14-friendly command for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this questions is about modded Minecraft

Comment: @FoxMcCloud No it isn't, and even if it was that's not off-topic in and of itself

Comment: What commands have you tried? How do they break in 1.14? There is no significant difference in the commands that I'm aware of.

Comment: perhaps @FoxMcCloud means that its not possible without mods.  If thats the case, then thats a good answer to the question. (I think thats true but not sure)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a command like this to give yourself a special ender pearl:

```
/give @s minecraft:ender_pearl{special:1}
```

You can use this command in a repeating command block to make any player holding a special ender pearl levitate:

```
/execute as @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:ender_pearl",tag:{special:1}}}] run effect give @s minecraft:levitation 1
```